# Error al crear un nuevo proyecto de vue

Tags: vue.js

Quiero crear un nuevo proyecto con el cli de vue junto con webpack con el siguiente comando

```
vue init webpack hello-world
```

Me salta el siguiente error

> Command vue init requires a global addon to be installed.
>
> Please run yarn global add @vue/cli-init and try again.

Al intentar ejecutar el comando alterior que salta el error

> error execa@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.
>
> Expected version ">=6". Got "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f"
>   error Found incompatible module.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de nodeJS tienes instalada?

Comment: @fredyfx La mas reciente, la `v12.16.0`

Comment: De acuerdo a https://nodejs.org, la más reciente es la `13.8.0`.  Para administrar varias versiones de node en el mismo equipo, te recomiendo usar esta herramienta https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows y si usas alguna distribución GNU/Linux o una Mac, esta es la misma herramienta https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 3):

El error que tienes es por efectos de incompatibilidad de versiones de nodejs

> error execa@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.
>
> Expected version ">=6". Got "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" error Found incompatible module.

Se soluciona instalando la versión más reciente de nodejs https://nodejs.org/ que a fecha de hoy 12 de febrero 2020, es la `13.8.0`.

Te sugiero hacer uso de esta herramienta:

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows y si usas alguna distribución GNU/Linux o una Mac, esta es la misma herramienta https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Esta herramienta te permitirá manejar diversas versiones de nodejs en el mismo equipo y poder cambiarlas sin problemas usando línea de comandos. La documentación está en los enlaces.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi version de Node a la `13.8.0` y me sigue saliendo el mismo error `error execa@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6". Got "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f"`

Comment: ¿Cambiaste la versión mediante el comando nvm use?

Comment: Si, la cambie con `nvm use 13.8.0` y con un `node -v` me salta la misma

Comment: intenta con este comando: `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: La instalacion fue exitosa pero al crear un nuevo proyecto me salta `Command vue init requires a global addon to be installed.
  Please run yarn global add @vue/cli-init and try again.`

Comment: `Vue-cli 3 is here, so this template is now considered deprecated.` extraído de: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack ahora bien, según la documentación ( https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create ) , deberías ejecutar `vue create hello-world`

Answer (score 0):

Debes de instalar todas las dependencia. para el dia de hoy tuve que instalar:

```
"cssnano": "^5.0.2",
"js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
"postcss-svgo": "^5.0.0",
"svgo": "^2.3.0",
"vue": "^2.6.12"

"css-loader": "^5.2.4",
```

vas verificando una a una puede que no sean iguales a las que arroja tu proyecto pero yo solucione de esa forma.

mis errores:

```
js-yaml  <=3.13.0
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/788
Code Injection - https://npmjs.com/advisories/813
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/js-yaml
  svgo  0.4.2 - 1.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of js-yaml
  node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/svgo
    postcss-svgo  <=2.1.6
    Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
    node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/postcss-svgo
      cssnano  3.0.0 - 3.10.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
      node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/cssnano
        css-loader  0.28.8 - 0.28.11
        Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
        node_modules/css-loader
```

### npm audit

Buscas el paquete aca:

### https://www.npmjs.com/packag

### npm i